# LibreOffice - Autocomplete dates

Tags: libreoffice

I've set the column cells to date format, English(Australian) but when I try to drag down a date to autofill, it simply copies the cell I'm dragging. So if I set DD/MM/YYYY in properties and type something like 21/08/2017, it will just copy 21/08/2017 instead of autofilling consecutive dates with no increment. I tried filling in two or three cells manually to drag, but it will still just copy (and now replace the subsequent two cells) with what's in the first cell. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the settings are not correct.  Go to Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages.  Verify that the `Date acceptance patterns` are `D/M/Y;D/M`.

[image: language settings]

Now, open a new spreadsheet, and in cell A1, type `21/08/2017`.  Then drag down to A5.  It should produce the following.

```
21/08/17
22/08/17
23/08/17
24/08/17
25/08/17
```